# Creating responsive CSS-Layout with nested containers

Tags: html, css, web

I got the following constellation of `<div>`-elements:

```
<div class="root">
    <div class="mainContainer">
        <div class="menuBarContainer"></div>
        <div class="appBoxContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Now, I want them to arrange on my page as depicted in the follwing picture:

[image]

Which would be the best way to arrange the `<div>` in CSS?
My problem is that the boxes try to fit in one line, even if I set the `width`-attribute to 100%.
I want the site to be fully responsive and the `sidebarContainer`-element is linked to a button which toggles its visibility.

What can I do to make the `mainContainer`-element take the full width of the page (`root`) when the sidebar is invisible (`width: 0`)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes), they're practically made for this desktop-application like layout.

Row [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) for for `.root`, column direction for `.mainContainer`

For responsive design you can use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to hide the `.sidebarContainer` below a certain screen size, even depending on device orientation.
Or simply change the root flexbox to column direction to display it below the main content.

Comment: The usage of flexboxes helped out and created the right `width`-dimensions. Unfortunately my `.mainContainer` now has a large horizontal white space and is simply cut at its bottom. I tried using `align-contents: flex-start` and that removed the white space, but the container is still cut not fully displayed

Comment: flexboxes should take up as much height as they need, unless you have constrained the height somehow. Maybe ask a new question with a jsfiddle example if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set (blue) boxes to `display:block` they  should clear automatically both sides and get positioned like your sketch;

Then , assuming your sidebar has a variable width  you could set

```
 .mainContainer {width: auto; display:inline-block}
```

Comment: `display: block` worked instantly. Somehow, the `.mainContainer` is now less wide than its child containers. What went wrong?

Comment: you need to clearfix (clearfix is exactly what is defined with the problem you're describing); [check this out!!](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)